# C++ SFINAE Resolution Order

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae, variadic-functions, enable-if

I have two functions

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args) { /* ... */ }

template <typename... Args>
void foo(const std::string& name, Args&&... args) { /* ... */ }
```

Currently all calls like `foo("bar", /* arguments */)` try to go to the first function instead of the second. I want to reorder these functions so that the SFINAE finds the second before the first. I cannot use `std::enable_if` to check for char array/string because the `Args...` pack might contain `std::string&` or `const char (&) []`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issues here is that `"bar"` is not a `std::string`.  No amount of reordering is going to get `void foo(const std::string& name, Args&&... args)` called since that would require a conversion while `void foo(Args&&... args)` will produce an exact match.

One workaround you can use the [literal string operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) and make `"bar"` a string using `"bar"s`.  This does require changing

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(const std::string& name, Args&&... args) { /* ... */ }
```

into

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(std::string&& name, Args&&... args) { /* ... */ }

template <typename... Args>
void foo(std::string& name, Args&&... args) { /* ... */ }
```

as `"bar"s` is a prvalue and would match your main function since that would deduce a rvalue reference which is preferred to a const lvalue reference.

Comment: or add an overload for `const char*`

Comment: Hmmm, wouldn't `foo("bar"s)` make the first argument an rvalue, which would still cause the first overload to be preferred?

Comment: @TristanBrindle Your right.  I forgot that it is a `const&` and not `&&`.  Should work now.

Comment: Okay... this seems to work. I am having some weird behavior. In my original code, if I add a function that accepts a `const char*`, then things work. However, if I replace `const std::string&` with `const char*`, it no longer resolves correctly. And idea what is happening here?

Comment: @subzero Without seeing the setup I couldn't guess.

Comment: @subzero I'd imagine that the problem is that that the type of the string literal "bar" is not `const char*`, but `const char[4]`, so the first overload will still be preferred as no array-to-pointer conversion is required.

Answer (score 7):

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args) { /* ... */ }
```

The trouble, as you've found, is that this function is greedy, and will match almost everything you throw at it. The only case in which the compiler will prefer another overload is if the argument type matches *exactly* -- if any sort of conversion is needed, then the compiler will prefer to instantiate the first template.

The most general way to work around this is to use SFINAE to disable the first overload if the first argument can be converted to a `std::string`, which we can test for using  the standard type trait `std::is_convertible`. With this approach, a suitable pair of overloads would be

```
// General case
template <typename First, typename... Rest,
          std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible<First, std::string>::value, int> = 0>
void foo(First&& first, Rest&&... rest) { ... }

// First argument can be converted to string
template <typename... Args>
void foo(const std::string& first, Args&&... args) { ... }
```

[Corilu link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/688b59af8c576600)

Comment: Note you additionally need a `void foo()` overload to match an invocation with an empty argument list, if we're shooting for accepting the same argument sets as OP's overloads.

Comment: @cdhowie True, I overlooked that one